# User is not permitted to deploy '.json' into Artifactory Using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, artifactory

I am trying to deploy a project jar into JFrog Artifactory using gradle. The `build.gradle` file looks like this (the part necessary for deploy):

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.16.1"
}
 configurations.classpath {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
 }
}

plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version '4.16.1'
  id 'maven-publish'
}


repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   mavenLocal()
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     maven {
        url "<artifactoryPath>/artifactory/gcc-maven/"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        groupId group
        version version
        from components.java
    }
  }
}

artifactory {
  contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
  publish {
    repository {
        repoKey = 'gcc-maven-local'
        username = "${artifactory_user}"
        password = "${artifactory_password}"
        maven = true
    }
  defaults {
        publications('mavenJava')
        publishArtifacts = true
        properties = ['version': version, 'dev.team': '<project>']
        publishPom = true
  }
}
  resolve {
    repository {
        repoKey = 'gcc-maven'
        username = "${artifactory_user}"
        password = "${artifactory_password}"
        maven = true
    }
  }
}
```

When I use my username and password everything works fine but when I use a token the *.jar* *.module* and *.pom* files are pushed but not the build descriptor. I have the next error:

```
> Task :artifactoryDeploy
Deploying build descriptor to: <artifactoryPath>/artifactory/api/build
Could not build the build-info object.
java.io.IOException: Failed to send build descriptor. 403 Response message: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 403,
    "message" : "User token:fim-artifactory-gcc-maven-rw-token is not permitted to deploy '<name>.json' into '<name>.json'."
  } ]
}
```

The token looks like this:

```
{

  "scope" : "member-of-groups:fim-artifactory-gcc-maven api:*",

  "access_token" : "<very_long_string>",

  "expires_in" : 0,

  "token_type" : "Bearer"

}
```

Some sites suggest that is a checkbox *Any Build* that must be checked but I don't find it and I think it might be a problem with **build.gradle** file.

What am I doing wrong?
It's there any possibility to skip the build descriptor at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out in [artifactory gradle documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin) that build descriptor can be ignored by setting `publishBuildInfo` to `false` in the defaults section. In my case it was what I was looking for.

Comment: `invokeMethod("setPublishBuildInfo", false)` for Gradle Kotlin users https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495123/gradle-kotlin-dsl-with-jfrog-artifactory-plugin-disable-publish-build-info/70426309#70426309

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting the same issue on Jfrog and setting publishBuildInfo = false solved the issue

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
        defaults {
            publishBuildInfo = false
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `invokeMethod("setPublishBuildInfo", false)` for Gradle Kotlin users https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495123/gradle-kotlin-dsl-with-jfrog-artifactory-plugin-disable-publish-build-info/70426309#70426309

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to skipping publishing of build info, see the screenshots on this GitHub issue for reference on enabling the required permissions:

https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/issues/120

[image: 'Any build' checkbox Artifactory permissions page]

[image: 'Build Actions' 'Deploy' checkbox Artifactory]